# Timer for turning LED's on for 4 seconds and then off for about 200 seconds

Tags: led, timer

I want to build a very small, low power timer that will allow several LED's on for 4 seconds and then off for about 200 seconds, then repeat. 4.5VDC. No programming.

Help please - thanks.

Comment: How can it be off for -200 seconds? Are we talking about time travel here?

Comment: I suspect that he is using shorthand for saying "about 200 seconds".  That is a sort of common way of speaking in my geographical area.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a tiny microcontroller (PIC10F family is good), you can do what you want by cascading two timers.

Have a look at the datasheet for a CD4060.  This is a CMOS multi-stage binary divider chip with built-in oscillator.  You can configure that chip to have a total period of 200 seconds.

The output of that chip feeds the trigger input of a TLC555 CMOS 555 timer chip via a coupling capacitor.  You can set the ON-time of the 555 to 4 seconds.

But using a PIC10F chip is much, much smaller and would consume less current.  I *really* like the PIC10F322 - very, very nice chip in a SOT23-6 package.

Comment: "very nice chip in a SOT23-6 package" -- the PIC10F322 is also available in an 8-pin DIP, which is better for experimenting and prototyping.  I agree it's a great little chip, including a configurable logic cell (CLC) front end.

Answer (score 3):

The 555 timer (LMC555) can be used to generate periodic pulses, the time periods of the pulses are determined by two resistors.

I know you stated no programming, but using a microcontroller (something like Microchip 8-bit PIC or something similar from Atmel) would be a more precise solution, probably also consuming less power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVaH5a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Actually, R2 should be about 280 M (nominal 277 M).

Comment: yes, the R2 should be 277MOhm from the equation in datashet. However, in the simulation the 180MOhm resistor gives almost the right period (200 s) due to the leakage currents. Even in the real circuit some experimentation with various values would be necessary.

Comment: A 200M\$\Omega\$ resistor sources ~15nA or so. For a standard LM555 (e.g., http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf), the input bias current for the threshold and trigger comparators ranges from 100 to 900nA (depending on which one you're looking at, and whether you're considering typical or max specs). I would *strongly* advise against using a circuit like this, unless you're using a CMOS-based 555 clone (and even so, humidity and finger oils start to contribute). Rather than using large resistor values, you should be using large capacitor values.